# How do you convert ProPhoto RGB colorspace to RGB with scikit-image and/or PIL?

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, scikit-image, color-space

I have TIF files that are in the ProPhoto RGB colorspace. These are imported fine with scikit-image's "imload" method. However, when I try to use matplotlib to view the image data I receive the error:

```
plt.imshow(myImage)

plt.show()
```

> Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).

The values are clipped to 255 and a totally white image is displayed. The error is correct about the image data as read by imread. The values look like:

```
myImage[0]
array([[60061, 60135, 60673],
   [59907, 59983, 60533],
   [59931, 60007, 60557],
   ...,
   [60649, 60801, 61147],
   [60581, 60743, 61091],
   [60647, 60797, 61143]], dtype=uint16)
```

These values obviously need to be scaled to obtain proper RGB values that range between 0-255.

When I open the image file in something like IrfanView and re-save it, the colorspace is handled properly as RGB (probably because IrfanView is converting it for me). However, I need to automate that conversion.

Is it possible to convert TIFs using the ProPhoto RGB colorspace to the RGB colorspace using either scikit-image or PIL (or something else)? I did not see any mention of that colorspace in the docs for the "color" module of scikit-image at https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.color.html. Unless "ProPhoto RGB" can be known by another name or compatible with another conversion method?

Thank you!

EDIT:

User Abhi25t's answer helped make some progress towards displaying these images. However, their answer appears to address only the 16-bit to 8-bit conversion. There is still a colorspace issue of ProPhoto RGB to sRGB. Hopefully this edit demonstrates this better.

The pixel values for the raw test TIF image in ProPhoto colorspace:

```
 array([[58465, 58479, 58785],
       [58575, 58591, 58879],
       [58441, 58457, 58739],
       ...,
       [58185, 58045, 58549],
       [58101, 57951, 58463],
       [57993, 57853, 58371]], dtype=uint16)
```

The pixel values for the Photoshop sRGB converted file:

```
array([[59771, 59873, 60161],
       [59863, 59965, 60235],
       [59755, 59855, 60119],
       ...,
       [59623, 59489, 59993],
       [59561, 59411, 59925],
       [59463, 59333, 59851]], dtype=uint16)
```

The pixel values for the IRFAN VIEW converted file (it appears to have converted to 8-bit AND translated to sRGB space):

```
array([[233, 233, 234],
       [233, 233, 234],
       [232, 233, 234],
       ...,
       [232, 231, 233],
       [232, 231, 233],
       [231, 231, 233]], dtype=uint8)
```

I have added some test code and images here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tcfUY2Kwlz-LAlt6_YXtT8l6vLnCucbM?usp=sharing

The image should display as a colorchecker target. You should be able to see it properly just plotting the imread result of "TEST_PROPHOTO_IRFAN_SAVED.tif".

```
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# TEST_PROPHOTO.tif : RAW TIF FILE
# TEST_PROPHOTO_IRFAN_SAVED.tif : RAW TIF, OPENED IN IRFANVIEW AND RESAVED AS TIF
# TEST_SRGB_PHOTOSHOP_CONVERTED.tif : RAW TIF, OPENED IN PHOTOSHOP, PROFILE CONVERTED TO sRGB, RESAVED AS TIF

img_path = '/path/to/image/myImage.tif'

img_rgb = io.imread(img_path)
plt.imshow(img_rgb)
plt.show()

# VIEW IMAGE CONTENTS
img_rgb[0] # you can see these values are 16-bit;
# however, colorspace (actual RGB values) differs between the ProPhoto test file and the Photoshop converted sRGB file

# STACKOVERFLOW USER Abhi25t's METHOD TO CONVERT FROM 16-bit color [0-65535] to 8-bit color [0-255]:
img_rgb_convert = img_rgb * (255/65535)
img_rgb_convert = img_rgb_convert.astype(int)
plt.imshow(img_rgb_convert)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe you can share a ProPhoto TIFF via Dropbox or GoogleDrive so folks can experiment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to perform the following steps:

1. Read the image with `imread`.
2. Convert to floating-point representation in range [0-1], i.e. convert to float and divide by 65535.
3. Decode with the [RIMM-ROMM RGB decoding function](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/f4040f1e4d17a326ed90492c2b51b4243ef4c64b/colour/models/rgb/transfer_functions/rimm_romm_rgb.py#L112).
4. Convert from RIMM-ROMM RGB gamut to sRGB gamut using the [required colour conversion matrix](https://www.colour-science.org:8010/apps/rgb_colourspace_transformation_matrix):

```py
# Using CAT02.
[[ 2.0364917242 -0.7375906525 -0.2992598689]
 [-0.2257179791  1.2231765313  0.0027252248]
 [-0.0105451286 -0.1348798497  1.1452101525]]
```

5. Encode with the [sRGB inverse Electro-Optical Transfer Function](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/f4040f1e4d17a326ed90492c2b51b4243ef4c64b/colour/models/rgb/transfer_functions/srgb.py#L43).
6. Convert to integer-representation in range [0-255], i.e. multiply by 255 and convert to integer.

[Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour) can do 3 to 5 directly using the [colour.RGB_to_RGB](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/f4040f1e4d17a326ed90492c2b51b4243ef4c64b/colour/models/rgb/rgb_colourspace.py#L1093) definition. Assuming the data is in floating-point range already, the conversion would be like to that:

```py
img_rgb_convert = colour.RGB_to_RGB(
    img_rgb,
    colour.RGB_COLOURSPACES['ProPhoto RGB'],
    colour.RGB_COLOURSPACES['sRGB'],
    chromatic_adaptation_transform='CAT02',
    apply_cctf_decoding=True,
    apply_cctf_encoding=True)
```

Note: Because *ProPhoto RGB* has a larger gamut than that of *sRGB*, it is possible that the conversion generates out-of-gamut colours, those can be clipped in the range [0-1] for simplicity after step 4 or 5 or gamut-mapped using a dedicated algorithm.

[image: ProPhoto RGB & sRGB]

Comment: Thank you! This is very close to a complete answer. However, I find when I implement this the values are strange. For example, after your Step 5, I run: 

    (img_rgb_convert * 255).astype('int')

(i.e., to perform your Step 6). This produces an array containing values as high as 287 and as low as -462 for my test file. Clipping them at 0 and 255 *seems* to produce valid results (though I'm not sure I'd be able to easily perceive any subtle color differences involved), but is that the correct approach?

Comment: Finally, I loaded in the IrfanView-converted file and used numpy.subtract to compare the RGB values with the non-clipped (img_rgb_convert * 255).astype('int')[Step 6 result]. This difference can range from -462 to +32. Comparing with the clipped img_rgb_convert yields a range of -23 to +24. That seems like a problem, unless the issue lies with IrfanView's conversion?

Comment: > This produces an array containing values as high as 287 and as low as -462 for my test file. This is not unexpected because ProPhoto RGB being a wider gamut than sRGB, you might get colours that are out-of-gamut. As an extra step, after 4 or 5, you could clamp your colours so that they are in the range 0-1.

Comment: Thank you again. That makes a lot of sense! What do you make of the difference between IrfanView-converted and the clipped "img_rgb_convert" results?

Comment: I’m not sure without being able to look at IrfanView code, as you saw, there are quite a few way that conversion can go wrong if not careful! They are for example maybe not doing chromatic adaptation which is required because the illuminants are different.

Comment: Thank you again for your excellent answers and help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert 16-bit resolution (of grayscale) to 8-bit here.

```
myImage = myImage * 255/65535
```

And then matplotlib will be able to display.

Convert your floats to int if required.

```
myImage = myImage.astype(int)
```

Comment: I think 255/65535 should be (255/65535)

This helped, however, a colorspace conversion problem remains. I have attempted to clarify my question.